# ¿cómo entender: "invalid syntax"?

Tags: python, print

Este es mi código:

```
print("("x_inf_izq, y_inf_izq")""("x_sup_izq, y_sup_izq")", "("x_inf_der,y_inf_der")", "("x_sup_der,y_sup_der")")
```

el error que me sale es:

```
print("("x_inf_izq, y_inf_izq")""("x_sup_izq, y_sup_izq")", "("x_inf_der,y_inf_der")", "("x_sup_der,y_sup_der")")
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Soy nueva en python y me gustaría aprender más, me ayudan por favor?

Comment: Bienvenido Dorys a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Trata de explicar lo que estas tratando de hacer para mejorar tu pregunta, a mi parecer estas tratando de concatener texto con variables dentro del `print ` para que en lugar de `"("x_inf_izq, y_inf_izq")"` imprima algo como `(2,2)`, pero ese es mi parecer por eso te pido expliques lo que tu intentas.

Comment: @RolandoTamayo gracias por la bienvenida y por tu comentario, lo que acabas de describir es lo que quiero hacer, pero no sé cómo. Qué me sugieres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problema:**

Al introducir

```
print("("x_inf_izq, y_inf_izq")""("x_sup_izq, y_sup_izq")", "("x_inf_der,y_inf_der")", "("x_sup_der,y_sup_der")")
```

En realidad se está haciendo

```
print(str int, int str str str int, int str, str int, int str, str int, int str )
```

Me explico:

Se está introduciendo una cadena de texto (str) y se le ha ubicado un número (int) al lado, tal que python no entiende qué operacion debe suceder entre estos, detecta un error por código no escrito correctamente (sintaxis) e indica su ubicación.

Como podrás ver, este error se te está repitiendo en todo el print, de hecho las `,` están actuando como separadores de parámetros en vez de como texto...

**Soluciones:**

Una **solución sencilla** pasa por la separación de parámetros:

```
print( "(", x_inf_izq, ", ", y_inf_izq, "), (", x_sup_izq, ", ", y_sup_izq, "), (", x_inf_der, ", ", y_inf_der, "), (", x_sup_der, ", ", y_sup_der, ")" )
```

Que es aceptable e implica:

```
print(str, int, str, int, str, int, str, int, str, int, str, int, str, int, str, int, str )
```

Una **solución más precisa** pasa por un sumatorio de cadenas de texto (str):

```
print( "(" + str(x_inf_izq) + ", " + str(y_inf_izq) + "), (" + str(x_sup_izq) + ", " + str(y_sup_izq) + "), (" + str(x_inf_der) + ", " + str(y_inf_der) + "), (" + str(x_sup_der) + ", " + str(y_sup_der) + ")" )
```

También aceptable e implica:

```
print(str + str(int) + str + str(int) + str + str(int) + str + str(int) + str + str(int) + str + str(int) + str + str(int) + str + str(int) + str )
```

Una **alternativa más limpia** es emplear el formateo de cadenas de texto:

```
print( "({},{}), ({},{}), ({},{}), ({},{})".format(x_inf_izq, y_inf_izq, x_sup_izq, y_sup_izq, x_inf_der, y_inf_der, x_sup_der, y_sup_der) )
```

Que implica:

```
print( str.format(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) )
```

Más información del formateo [aquí](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting).

Espero que sea útil ;)

Answer (score 2):

El mensaje de error se debe a que estas juntando dos cosas (un string y una variable) sin un operador entre medio.

Si quieres producir un resultado que se vea asi:

```
(23, 47)
```

la forma más sencilla es así:

```
print("(", 23, ", ", 47, ")")
```

produce:

```
( 23 ,  47 )
```

Un poco más elegante, con formato:

```
print("(%d,%d)" % (23, 47))
```

produce:

```
(23,47)
```

En este caso, creas un string de formato escribiendo `%d` donde quieres reeemplazar un valor. Luego del string agregas "%", seguido de la tupla con los valores a reemplazar.

Finalmente, a partir de Python 3.7, tienes los f-strings: simplemente escribes un puro string, encerrando entre `{ }` la expresión que quieres evaluar:

```
x_inf_izq = 23
y_inf_izq = 47
print(f"({x_inf_izq}, {y_inf_izq})")
```

produce:

```
(23, 47)
```